# systemctl list-unit-files, but do not list aliases

Tags: systemd

Is there a way to stop `systemctl list-unit-files` from printing aliases?

Example:

```
foohost:~ # systemctl list-unit-files | grep -i http
httpd.service                                   enabled
```

Checking it:

```
foohost:~ # systemctl status httpd.service
● apache2.service - The Apache Webserver
```

"https.service" is just an alias.

I am writing some script to check the status and it would be very nice if aliases are not listed.

Comment: Why are you using `list-unit-files` then? You probably should be using `list-units` with appropriate options.

Comment: @MichaelHampton very good question. I just update the check-script, I was not the initial author. Yes, `list-units` might be better. Thank you